# Why Bulk Edit is not working in Woocommerce Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was working to add some function with products in bulk edit dropdown.

And i used this code. I got this in dropdown but when select product and click on apply i got error ever i tried to echo something at handle_bulk_actions-edit-product filter but i did not get anything.

Any Suggestion what i am doing wrong ?

```
add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-product', function($bulk_actions) {
    $bulk_actions['sync_products'] = __('Sync Products', 'txtdomain');
    return $bulk_actions;
});
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-product', 'wpmis_sync_bulk_product', 10, 3 );

function wpmis_sync_bulk_product($redirect_url, $action, $post_ids) {
    if ($action == 'sync_products') {
        foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
            echo $post_id;
        }
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg('sync_products', count($post_ids), $redirect_url);
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_action('admin_notices', function() {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['sync_products'])) {
        $num_changed = (int) $_REQUEST['sync_products'];
        printf('<div id="message" class="updated notice is-dismissable"><p>' . __('Products %d synced.', 'txtdomain') . '</p></div>', $num_changed);
    }
});
```

Comment: undefined function wpims_sync_selected_products

Comment: Kindly commit out just make echo something or print_r products ids